# not able to access EC2 instance configured with nginx using public IP

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I'm trying to configure nginx to access PWA app installed on EC2 instance using public IP but it's not working ( going to IP address nothing loads ).

nginx.conf is as below

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

events {
        worker_connections 1024;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {
    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include         /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type    application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;


    server {
      listen       80 default_server;
      listen       [::]:80 default_server;

     client_max_body_size 50M;

     server_name  xx.xxx.xx.x; #EC2 public IPV4
     root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

     return 301 https://$host$request_uri;


                location /admin/api/users {
                    proxy_set_header   X-uri $uri;
                    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
                    proxy_pass         http://localhost:9090/users;
                }

                location /admin/api/ {
                    proxy_set_header   X-uri $uri;
                    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
                    proxy_pass         http://localhost:8080/;
                }
                location /admin/ {
                    proxy_set_header   X-uri $uri;
                    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
                    proxy_pass         http://localhost:3030/;
                }
            location /api/ {
                proxy_set_header   X-uri $uri;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
                proxy_pass         http://localhost:8080/;
            }
            location / {
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
                proxy_pass         http://localhost:3000/;
            }

            error_page 404 /404.html;
                location = /40x.html {
            }

            error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
                location = /50x.html {
            }
                    }
                }
```

When I open EC2 public IP address it says "site can not be reached"

```
ubuntu@ip-xxx-xx-x-xx:~$ sudo systemctl status nginx
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2019-10-04 13:20:07 UTC; 8min ago
     Docs: man:nginx(8)
  Process: 8704 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 8694 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 8708 (nginx)
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 1152)
   CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
           ├─8708 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
           └─8711 nginx: worker process

Oct 04 13:20:07 ip-xxx-xx-x-xx systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Oct 04 13:20:07 ip-xxx-xx-x-xx systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed to parse PID from file /run/nginx.pid: Invalid argument
Oct 04 13:20:07 ip-xxx-xx-x-xx systemd[1]: Started A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

I'm learning nginx, please advise how to debug and fix this issue ?

Comment: Have you set IAM permissions to open port 80 and 443 ?

Comment: I've logged in as admin user added in IAM and could see 2 groups "launch-wizard-1" and "default" both has got ports enabled

Comment: @vikrami I see you're missing "root" parameter in your configuration, could you add it? http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root

Comment: I've added it under server_name and restarted nginx but still can't access the website, how to debug to find root cause

Comment: server name should be the dns name, it doesn't work with IP address. I'd suggest to comment out "server_name" and try configuration without it.

Comment: can you please clarify by commenting out server_name where should I mention EC2 public IP address ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200431/discussion-between-vikramvi-and-andrea).

Comment: @Andrea can you please clarify